# Adding --data to R curl_fetch_memory()

Tags: r, curl

I want to create an R script to use instead of a curl request.

Using curl, I use a Google API which requires the --data option. I am not sure how to add this option to my curl request using the curl package.

The request that works using Git Bash is as follows:

```
API_KEY="[xyz]"
curl "https://chromeuxreport.googleapis.com/v1/records:queryHistoryRecord?key=$API_KEY" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
–-data '{"url": "https://www.example.com/"}'
```

This is my R code, which doesn't send the necessary URL to return anything good:

```
library(curl)
```

```
API_KEY = "xyz"
h <- new_handle()
handle_setheaders(h,
  "Content-Type" = "application/json"
)

r <- curl_fetch_memory(url = paste0("https://chromeuxreport.googleapis.com/v1/records:queryHistoryRecord?key=",API_KEY), h)
```

So how can I add the --data option using the curl package?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the `curl` library as opposed to a more high level package like `httr`? If you used `httr` it would look like `httr::contents(httr::POST(paste0("https://chromeuxreport.googleapis.com/v1/records:queryHistoryRecord?key=", API_KEY), body = list(url = "https://www.example.com/"), encode = "json"))`

Comment: I have it working with httr, but wanted to use the curl library to minimize dependencies. If there's no way to make this work with curl, I'm fine with httr, albeit disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lower-level `curl` if you really want to. In this case your original CURL command is performing a POST action with a JSON encoded body. The equivalent of that in the R curl library would be

```
library(curl)

API_KEY <- "xyz"
url <- paste0("https://chromeuxreport.googleapis.com/v1/records:queryHistoryRecord?key=", API_KEY)
payload <- charToRaw('{"url": "https://www.example.com/"}')

h <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(h, post=TRUE, postfields=payload)
handle_setheaders(h, "Content-Type" = "application/json")
r <- curl_fetch_memory(url = url, h)

cat(rawToChar(r$content))
```